# Getting rid of blank pages

Tags: page-breaking, blank-page

I have a file with two appendices, each of which contains only a figure, and a blank page is being inserted before each appendix page. I have tried looking for an answer, but it seems like everything I find relates to the book document type, and I am using the report. My document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside, letterpaper, 12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Database Layout}
        \includegraphics[max size={.98\textwidth}]{DatabaseDiagram}
    \chapter{Website Layout (as relates to database)}
        \includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}]{WebsiteDiagram}
\end{appendices}    

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. I've edited your question to put it into this format. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: I think, your example requires `\usepackage{appendix}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! — @ChristianHupfer It's also a package?

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` requires the `appendix` package

Comment: I am using the appendices package. I edited my post to include more of my code.

Answer (score 1):

After correcting your MWE a little bit that it works, it gives result as you desire:

```
\documentclass[oneside, letterpaper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{bla}
    \lipsum[1]
  \appendix
%  \renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}% possible alternative
  \renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
%    \section{Database Layout}
    \chapter{Database Layout}
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-A}
%    \section{Website Layout (as relates to database)}
    \chapter{Website Layout (as relates to database)}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-B}
\end{document}
```

As you can se from above WME, pages has not blank pages before any chapter. If You can instead `chapter` as document division in appendix use `section`. In  latter case you can obtain two images in one page (if they are enough small).

**Update:**
As mentioned Christian Hupfer, `appendix` isn't environment, so (if the appendix is on the end of document) should be used as `\appendix`. I correct this in above code and also changy stile of numbering from small caps to big one.

Comment: `appendix` is no environment, unless `appendix` package is used, then it's `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}`, as was the original version in the OP

Comment: Probably you have right, bud appendices -- to my surprise -- doesn't work in OP example.

Comment: Do you refer to the blank pages? I assume, they will still appear with `appendix` package

Comment: In given example of OP is select option ``oneside``. Because of it there is no blank page before appendix. For two side option situation is different.